# Question on limits and continuity...

Tags: calculus, limits

I was just wondering once you know that $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)$ at an interior point in the domain of $f$, do you then know that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$?

Any reasons would be great thanks!!!

Comment: It is true. Just apply the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)$$ then you can prove that this common  value is $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$

Let the common value be $L$

For a given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta _1$ such that if $a<x<a+\delta_1$ then $ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon $

Similarly  there is a $\delta _2$ such that if $a-\delta_2 <x<a$ then $ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon $

Let $\delta < \min \{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$

If $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^{+}} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^{-}}f(x)$. If not, we say that the limit at $a$ **is not defined in the domain of the function** $f$.

Note that, a function is a 3-tuple with (Domain, Counterdomain, Association Rule). So, the association rule may fail for a specific domain when taken the limit, but it may work for other domains.